# How to display POST values which are coming from javascript XMLHttpRequest() in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am sending parameters using XMLHttpRequest() javascript function to another php page in Json formate, but $_POST['appoverGUID']  not getting post values.

Here is my Javascript code.

```
        function loadPage(href){

            var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = json.php;
            var approverGUID = "Test";
            var params = JSON.stringify({ appoverGUID: approverGUID });
            http.open("POST", url, true);
            http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
            http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
             http.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML = http.responseText;

                }
            } 
            http.send(params);

        }
```

And here is my **json.php** file code.

```
if(isset($_POST['appoverGUID'])){
echo $_POST['appoverGUID'];
}
```

Comment: Is your JS variable named `approverGUID`, or is this a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all remove these headers since they will be send automatically by the browser and it's the right way to do it.

```
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
```

This code is a cross browser solution and it's tested.

```
// IE 5.5+ and every other browser
var xhr = new(window.XMLHttpRequest || ActiveXObject)('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
var params = "appoverGUID="+approverGUID;
xhr.open("POST", url, true);

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
        }
    }
}
xhr.send(params);
xhr = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use `json_decode`. Some like this:

```
if ("application/json" === getallheaders())
    $_JSON = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true) ?: [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Fill params this way (did no escaping/encoding of approverGUID content, here..):

```
params = "appoverGUID="+approverGUID;
```

Also see:

http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php